# Shell line 7: [14: command not found

Tags: shell, terminal, sh

I don't know what is the problem to fix Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
HOUR=$(date '+%H')
TARGET=16
echo $HOUR
if [$HOUR -gt $TARGET];
then
mail -s "IP" "example@hotmail.com" <<EOF
Global_IP=$(curl -s checkip.dyndns.org | sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//')
EOF
echo "Sent"
fi
echo "Waiting..."
sleep 3600
echo "Done waiting"
done
```

Please help!

Comment: Is it failing at the `mail`? Have you tried this line by itself on your command line?

Comment: The title gives it away: the problem is before/in line 7, `if [$HOUR -gt $TARGET];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add blanks after `[` and before `]`:

```
if [ $HOUR -gt $TARGET ];
```